# Mysql doesnt export or import all the data from tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a very strange situation. I have exported 3 tables from my webserver and i have tried to import it on the local machine, but there is a difference between both row results.

To export the data i have used:

```
mysqldump -u user -p db_name table1 table2 table3 > file.sql
```

To import the data i have used:

```
mysql -u user -p db_name < file.sql
```

There is no change on the server, so there is a big difference. On the server i have in one table (1793104 rows) and local i have (1780731 rows).

Any ideas why is that ? I see that results in phpmyadmin and it shows sometimes different results, but this time i think that is not the problem ?

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 360
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It comes from phpmyadmin. I need to write select count (*) from table to see the real resulst.

Answer (score 0):

Change below parameters in .ini file

max_execution_time
max_input_time
memory_limit

Comment: i made this changes, but it still does not import every row. The number of imported rows is pretty random.

Comment: it is different with each attempt and it is always less than the real number of rows. The difference is between 5-3k rows.